# Google AppEngine blacklist page shows server error

Tags: google-app-engine

Google AppEngine blacklist page shows server error, I have tried removing all contents of dos.yaml file and it still shows the server error, the blacklist was showing fine until like 5 days ago. Attached is screenshot[image]

Comment: Looks like it was something on app_engine side, issue resolved after few weeks without me doing anythin

Answer (score 0):

Then the error is probably not caused by the `dos.yaml` file.  Open the [Applications list](https://appengine.google.com/) in your browser and select your application to see the Dashboard.  Click on the `Logs` link (third one down on the left) to see the actual error.